Keep current region of dynamic cells
I have a dynamic index sheet (here fruit and animal types are shown as an example, actually there are more than that two types, each workbook has different number of types with different length of horizon):

My goal is to extract the index values in a standardized table in a new sheet like this:

Since the location of index name, index values are dynamic, I am trying to select and keep current regions of highlighted red cells.
Sub HighlightAndKeep()
    
    Dim cl As Range

    If Not cl Is Nothing And cl.Font.Color = 3 Then        
           
    cl.CurrentRegion.select  ' how to keep the selected regions is the part i am facing challenge 
            
    End If

End Sub

How do I keep the selected current regions (if can directly select & keep the index & index value cell, remove the rest cells, that would be great) and remove the rest not needed cells, then achieving the target table?
Alternative approach suggestions are welcome.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

Something like set cl = range("A12").CurrentRegion would get A12:L13
Not clear for me which region you want.

the curent region of all red highlighted index cells (red cells, below few cells that include the index value)

The code is tested using the sample data in the original post.

The IndexN cell should be in the same row as the table header, with the index values listed below the IndexN cell.
There is a gap (one or more blank cells) between the IndexN cell and table header.

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim c As Range, d As Range, arrRes(), iR As Long
    Dim sCate As String, sIdx As String, iIdx As Double
    Dim oCol As New Collection, i As Long
    Set c = Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    Do
        sCate = c.Value: sIdx = Empty: iIdx = 0
        ' Locate IndexN cell
        Set d = c.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight)
        If UCase(Left(d.Value, 5)) = "INDEX" Then
            sIdx = d.Value
            If IsEmpty(d.Offset(1)) Then
                ' Locate Index value
                Set d = d.End(xlDown)
                If IsNumeric(d.Value) And Not IsEmpty(d) Then
                    iIdx = d.Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
'        Debug.Print sCate, sIdx, iIdx
        ' Add to Coll.
        oCol.Add Array(sCate, sIdx, iIdx)
        ' Locate the next block
        Set c = c.End(xlDown).End(xlDown)
    Loop Until c.Row = Rows.Count
    ' populate array
    ReDim arrRes(oCol.Count, oCol.Count)
    For i = 1 To oCol.Count
        arrRes(0, i) = oCol(i)(1)
        arrRes(i, 0) = oCol(i)(0)
        arrRes(i, i) = oCol(i)(2)
    Next
    ' write to sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(oCol.Count + 1, oCol.Count + 1) = arrRes
End Sub



